# Openlayers 2 getLonLatFromLayerPx() gives wrong coords after pan

Tags: openlayers-2

I'm trying to display mouse position on external div (ExtJS based) using this code :

```
map.events.register("mousemove", map, function(e) {

        position = map.getLonLatFromLayerPx(this.events.getMousePosition(e));
        position = position.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"));            
        Ext.fly(mouseposition.getEl()).update("Lat (N): " + position.lat.toFixed(4) + "   Long (E): " + position.lon.toFixed(4) );
    });
```

The problem is that when I pan the map than the coords I get are the original from before the pan , only if I zoom in/out than I get the correct coords from the mouse position.

How can I fix this ?

Here is example (**look on the coords on the bottom of the map**) :

1. Initial load over Israel , see the lat/lon of the mouse.

[image]

2. I pan over to europe , lat/lon stay around the same values of the original map extent

[image]

3. I zoom in and back out and the lat/lon update to the current map view extent range.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by *"the coords I get are the original from before the pan"*? The `mousemove` event is not triggered? Did you try debugging? Note that `position` should be a local variable. You can easily test your code directly on http://openlayers.org/two/ by using Chrome JS console (just replace Ext stuff with `console.log`), output looks more or less OK. BTW. the logic seems flawed anyway because the same place returns different lat/lon depending on which part of the div it's in - not sure if converting mouse position to lat/lon makes any sense from geographical POV.

Comment: I've updated with screenshots to explain the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `getLonLatFromPixel` instead of `getLonLatFromLayerPx`. Unfortunately the latter method is not documented at all ([see here](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.getLonLatFromLayerPx)) so I'll leave it to you to investigate where they differ.

You can easily verify this by going to http://openlayers.org/two/ and pasting the following code in your JS console:

```js
map.events.register("mousemove", map, function(e) {
  var position = map.getLonLatFromPixel(this.events.getMousePosition(e));
  position = position.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"));
  console.log("Lat (N): " + position.lat.toFixed(4) + "   Long (E): " + position.lon.toFixed(4));
});
```

Now grabbing and dragging an area using your mouse will show that lon/lat stays the same, that is - correct.

Note that if you try the same code with `getLonLatFromLayerPx` instead the coordinates "slide" along with the map that you're dragging which is clearly wrong (and this is what I descripbed in my comment under your question).

---

If I misunderstood your description please try to create a function that's easily reproducible, e.g. by pasting on http://openlayers.org/two/ and watching the JS console.

Comment: I've used map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx and it sovled the problem.

Comment: Just tried your solution and it also works.